# I need that when I send an email through Outlook using code written in C# it is sent with the email signature

Tags: c#, outlook

```
    private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Crear una instancia de Outlook
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

            // Crear un objeto de correo electrónico
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            // Obtener la firma del correo electrónico
            string signature = GetOutlookSignature();

            // Establecer la firma en el correo electrónico
            mailItem.HTMLBody = signature + "<br><br>";

            // Establecer los campos del correo electrónico
            mailItem.To = "administradorti2@myolegal.com";
            mailItem.Subject = "Asunto del correo electrónico";
            mailItem.Body = "Cuerpo del correo electrónico";

            if (lstAdjuntos.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (string filePath in lstAdjuntos.Items)
                {
                    // Adjuntar el archivo al objeto MailItem
                    mailItem.Attachments.Add(@filePath.ToString());
                }
            }

            // Enviar el correo electrónico
            mailItem.Send();

            // Liberar recursos
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookApp);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The code that I share already sends the email but it is sent without the signature, which I already have configured in Outlook, well, the button code also uses the following method to obtain the signature.

```
    public static string GetOutlookSignature()
    {
        // Obtener la ruta de la carpeta de firmas de Outlook
        string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string signatureFolder = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Microsoft\\Signatures");

        // Obtener la firma predeterminada de Outlook
        string signatureFile = Path.Combine(signatureFolder, "default.htm");

        if (File.Exists(signatureFile))
        {
            // Leer el contenido del archivo de firma
            string signature = File.ReadAllText(signatureFile, Encoding.UTF8);

            // Reemplazar las rutas absolutas de las imágenes por rutas relativas
            if (signature.Contains("<img"))
            {
                string baseFolder = signatureFolder;
                Regex regex = new Regex("src=[\"']([^\"']*)[\"']", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(signature);

                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    string absolutePath = match.Groups[1].Value;

                    if (absolutePath.StartsWith("file://"))
                    {
                        absolutePath = absolutePath.Substring(7);
                    }

                    if (absolutePath.StartsWith("/"))
                    {
                        absolutePath = absolutePath.Substring(1);
                    }

                    string relativePath = absolutePath.Replace(baseFolder, ".");
                    signature = signature.Replace(absolutePath, relativePath);
                }
            }

            return signature;
        }
        else
        {
            // No se encontró la firma predeterminada
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Library used:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

I am not an advanced programmer yet and I have helped myself from artificial intelligence to get that function that gets the signature but it didn't really help me, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You are sending  a MIME attachment in the body of an email.  Each Mime Attachment starts with two dashes on a new line (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140))/  You are adding each attachment in the for loop and reading from "mailItem.Attachments.Add(@filePath.ToString());".  Each attachment needs a signature if each image is a separate Mime Attachment. Or you can put one signature on the entire email.  Your code is doing neither. To have one signature you would need to read all the MIME body, and then add signature.

Answer (score 0):

The following line completely wipes out the existing body (including the signature)

```
mailItem.Body = "Cuerpo del correo electrónico";
```

There is no reason to set the plain text body if you already set `HTMLBody` just a few lines above. Also note that you cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML back - the two must be merged. Find the position of `"<body"`, find the next `">"`, and insert your HTML text after that.